# Single MixedIndex with multiple properties OR multiple MixedIndexes with single property each?

Tags: database-design, titan

I am using Titan 1.0.0 with Cassandra as storage backend and elasticsearch as indexing backend, want to model a complex graph with multiple vertices and edges. I've following considerations to make:

1. Should I chose to have multiple MixedIndexes with single property each OR single MixedIndex with multiple properties?

   ```
   mgmt.buildIndex('nameAndAge',Vertex.class).addKey(name,Mapping.TEXT.getParameter()).addKey(age,Mapping.TEXT.getParameter()).buildMixedIndex("search")
   ```

OR

```
mgmt.buildIndex('nameMixed',Vertex.class).addKey(name,Mapping.TEXT.getParameter()).buildMixedIndex("search")
mgmt.buildIndex('ageMixed',Vertex.class).addKey(age,Mapping.TEXT.getParameter()).buildMixedIndex("search")
```

> if I've to chose singel Mixed index with multiple properties
>   then can it span across properties on edges and vertices OR is there
>   any guideline?

2. Is it better to have properties shared across Vertices / Edges? 
   Meaning I want to have property "onDate" and have it for edges "Registered", "MarriedTo", "AgreedToTerms" and vertices "Order", "Travel".

> Shall there be any special considerations if that property need to
>   have index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here at what documatation says

> Mixed indexes retrieve vertices or edges by any combination of previously added property keys.

#### And now for your first question,

- if you aim at using single index to query any/all of the properties at one, use just one mixed index. Say you want to have one single

Example

```
String query="v.*:Phani"; // searches any property in the index with a value that includes `Phani`
Iterable<TitanIndexQuery.Result<TitanVertex>> result = titanGraph.indexQuery("name_mixed_index", query).vertices();
```

This searches all properties of the mixed index you created. If you added 10 properties added to this index, it will search the 10 and so on.

- If you aim at querying one property only then use composite index. It's much faster.

My recommendation, use a single mixed index for all properties of interest so you could query them all at once or query them with any combination you like. If you want a single index, use composite index for it.

#### For your second question,

You can't share the same property value across indexes and edges. But you could have the same name of the property among all of them. If you intend to query a single property, aim for composite indexes.

#### In short,

Interested in making a query that includes multiple values or involve ordering? use mixed index with multiple properties. #
Interested in making a query on only one property, use composite index.

More about this, read the documentation [here for Indexing in Titan 1.0.0](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer @M-T-A, from your answer to the first question, my interest is not to query on the index directly, rather I want to do my general gremlin traversals. In a vertex, out of 10 properties, assuming I've 5 in one mixed indx. Can I query using only two properties in one gremlin traversal and remaining 3 in another traversal? Or for such a case, would it be beneficial to have 2 in one mixed index and 3 in other?

Comment: From the answer to the second question, would it be OK to have a same named property in vertex and edge? would I be able to apply index in such case? because, for vertex and edge the indexes are differently formed!

Comment: You could have 5 of them in one index and perform whatever you want with them. It will work the same in both cases with 1 or 2 separate indexes.

Comment: You have to create two separate indexes for properties of edges and properties of vertices. So they can have the same name. Check docs http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/javadoc/1.0.0/com/thinkaurelius/titan/graphdb/database/management/ManagementSystem.html

Comment: Thank you for your time and answers @M-T-A